# Nuxt.js - How do I use vue-i18n outside components?

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I'm using the plugin [vue-i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-i18n) for translations in a Nuxt.js-powered SPA. This allows easy access to messages **within components**, like this:

```
$t('footer.press')
```

But how do I get translations **outside components**? In my specific case, I need them in a [store](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store) action:

```
export const actions = {

  async myAction({ commit, state, rootState, rootGetters }, options) {

    (...)

    const message = $t("example.message.key")             // doesn't work, undefined
    const message1 = this.$i18n.t("example.message.key")  // doesn't work, undefined

    (...)

    })

  }
```

This is how I include the vue-i18n plugin in the project:

**package.json**

```
…
 "dependencies": {
        …
        "vue-i18n": "^8.18.2",
        …
    },
…
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
…
plugins: [
        …
        '~/plugins/i18n',
        …
    ],
…
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found a working solution on the Vue Forum [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-use-t-from-vue-i18n-inside-vuex-action/22146/3):

```
const message = this.app.i18n.t("example.message.key")
```

Works for me like a charm!

Comment: There need to be explain, how you manage to to have `app.i18n` available as it will crash (ErrorType) when call `this.app.i18n`

Comment: @Osify I added more info to the question, hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for update, I think, it's not matched to my case, I am using nuxt-i18n module, I write some javascript helper as an util outside the component and which suppose to call it when need in Vue component stuffs, I still cannot make the translation done in the helper js, either via this.app, via Vue.i18n etc.

Comment: @Osify To leverage reactivity system, your helper must return a i18n key identifier which will be used inside the downstream component. Therefore, when the current locale change at runtime, you get instantly new translations !

Answer (score -1):

```
this.$t('logInWongCredentials')
```

(nuxt)

Comment: You missed the "outside component" part